# Controlling Servos with Arduino

Tags: arduino, servo

I am trying to control a small servo motor with an Arduino and I am running into a problem where the Servo continuously runs even when I want it to stop. I have pasted a picture of my code below. The for loops should make the Servo stop when it rotates 180 degrees, but it just keeps spinning.

I am trying to control the direction of the servos using the Serial monitor as input.

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo myservo;
int i = 0;

void setup() {
// put your setup code here, to run once:
Serial.begin(9600);
myservo.attach(9);

}

void loop() {
// put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
keyboardControl(); 
}

void keyboardControl() {
if (Serial.available() > 0) {
int data = Serial.read();
switch (data) {
  case '1' :
    for (i = 0; i <= 180; i += 1) {
      myservo.write(i);
      delay(15);
      if (i = 180) {
        break;
      }
    case '2':
      for (i = 180; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
        myservo.write(i);
        delay(15);
        break;
      }

    }
}
} 
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to post the code as text, not as a screenshot. It's easier for others to help you troubleshoot if they can copy/paste your code and reproduce your problem.

Comment: @JanBoyer I edited the code so that it is easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

I would give this code a try:

```
void stop()

    {
     while(1 = 180);
    }
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: The code above is something I used on one of my Arduino projects last year. It simply just stop's after it recognizes that the loop of 1 = 180 degrees.